# How to connect wowza media server from ios device through http?

Tags: wowza

We are implementing an app in xcode for live streaming which uses the url http://[wowza address]:1935/application to connect the wowza server, but there is no connection established 
What are the server side changes to be implemented in addition to the application.xml to connect the server?

Answer (score 0):

When publishing via http, Wowza does not support that. You can see a list of supported codecs for inbound streams [here](https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine/specifications).

You can publish using rtmp or rtsp from ios / mac app and you can have a look at a variety of projects that will do that.  You can take a look at their [GoCoder solution](https://www.wowza.com/products/gocoder) for comparison.